# How to support multiple screen sizes in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, sprite-kit

I want to make universal game that support all iOS devices , beside making the project how to make my game support all screen sizes is there is a way to detect the screen size by code and change the graphic and the code according to the size , and what should the resolution of the graphics for each device ?

Comment: This question has already been asked many times.

Comment: i didn't found exactly what i want

Comment: Then for clarity you should add more detail to your question on what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to determine the width and height of the screen. You can also find out what device is being used.

```
    struct ScreenSize
{
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType
{
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P         = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
}
```

You can `println()` the values in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Well, GameScene should inherit from `SKScene`, which you can get the size, width, and height of by doing: `self.frame.size`,`self.frame.width`, and`self.frame.height` respectively.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/CoordinateSystem.html) link may also help you.