# After Showing Interstitial Ad when GameOver, scene return to WelcomeScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob

I have a sprite kit game and I want to show interstitial ad when the game is over. Well, I am able to show the ad after when the game over using `NotificationCenter`but the problem is that when the I close the ad, it returns to the WelcomeScene. I want to return to the GameOverScene after closing the ad but how? 
GameViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController , GADInterstitialDelegate {


var interstitialAds : GADInterstitial!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    createAndLoadAd()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.showAds), name: NSNotification.Name("notification"), object: nil)


}


func createAndLoadAd(){
    let request = GADRequest()
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.load(request)
    interstitialAds = interstitial
}

func showAds(){

    if interstitialAds.isReady {
        interstitialAds.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    createAndLoadAd()
}


override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let menu = Menu()
    let skView = self.view as! SKView

    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    menu.size = view.bounds.size
    menu.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.resizeFill
    skView.presentScene(menu)


}
```

}

GameScene.swift

```
    func gameOver(){

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("notification"), object: nil)

    //reset everything
    self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Sound/die.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
    hud.updateScore(score: Int(score))


    player.die()
    hud.showScore()
    hud.showRestartMenu()



}
```

HUD.swift

```
    import SpriteKit

    class HUD : SKNode {
    var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "0")
    let restartBut = SKSpriteNode()
    let menuBut = SKSpriteNode()
    let highScoreLabel = SKLabelNode()

    func createNode(screenSize : CGSize){

    scoreLabel.fontName = "AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold"
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: (screenSize.width / 2) - (screenSize.width / 4 * 2) , y: (screenSize.height / 2) - 50)
    scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.black
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 40
    scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
    scoreLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.center
    scoreLabel.zPosition = 50
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)

     //Restart and Menu button
    restartBut.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "restartButton")
    restartBut.name = "restartButton"
    restartBut.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    restartBut.zPosition = 50
    restartBut.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)

    menuBut.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "menuButton")
    menuBut.name = "menuButton"
    menuBut.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -300)
    menuBut.zPosition = 50
    menuBut.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)

    highScoreLabel.fontName = "AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold"
    highScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 450)
    highScoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.black
    highScoreLabel.fontSize = 45
    highScoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
    highScoreLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.center
    highScoreLabel.zPosition = 50
    }

    func showRestartMenu(){

    restartBut.alpha = 0
    menuBut.alpha = 0
    highScoreLabel.alpha = 0

    self.addChild(restartBut)
    self.addChild(menuBut)
    self.addChild(highScoreLabel)

    restartBut.run(SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1, duration: 0.35))
    menuBut.run(SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1, duration: 0.35))
    highScoreLabel.run(SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1, duration: 0.35))





    }

    func updateScore(score : Int){
    var highScore = UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "highScore")
    let number = NSNumber(value: score)
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()

    if let scoreText = formatter.string(from: number){
        scoreLabel.text = scoreText
    }




    if Int(score) > highScore {
        highScore = Int(score)
        highScoreLabel.text = NSString.init(format: "Highscore : %i", highScore) as String

        let highScoreDefs = UserDefaults.standard
        highScoreDefs.set(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
        highScoreDefs.synchronize()

    }

    highScoreLabel.text = "Highscore : \(highScore)"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `GameViewController` and move all the code from `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` into `ViewDidLoad`. `ViewDidLoad` is only called once when the `GameViewController` loads. `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` on the other hand can be called multiple times, like when your ad is shown, which will than load your MenuScene again.

As a tip you should put your notification keys into an extension to avoid typos and be more specific with the names as a matter of good practice.

So add this above any class or in a new swift file

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let showAd = Notification.Name("ShowAdNotification")
}
```

Than you can change your observers to this

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showAds), name: .showAd, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .showAd, object: nil)
```

You can also check out my helper on GitHub if you want to have a cleaner more reusable solution.

https://github.com/crashoverride777/SwiftyAds

I also noticed that you are using `.resizeFill` in your `GameViewController` scale mode. You should not do this, your game will look different on each device and it will be a nightmare to manage. You should use the default scaleMode `.aspectFill` which is usually the best setting.

You should also give the scene a fixed size and not size it depending on the bounds of the view (view.bounds.size).

[How to make SKScene have fixed width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878452/how-to-make-skscene-have-fixed-width/42886511#42886511)

[How do I size sprites in a universal sprite kit game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941265/how-do-i-size-sprites-in-a-universal-sprite-kit-game/42949937#42949937)

Hope this helps

Comment: I have updated the code. When the player( game character) die, and the ads shows up and when I close the ad, the current scene disappear and instead it shows the Menu scene(which is the first scene after my app launches....*sry, not WelcomeScene by the way* ). I was expecting it to show me the restartButton which I added it into HUD and addchild to HUD when game is over.

Comment: I still dont see code that indicates that any scene transition is happening.  Please show the transition code that takes you to GameOverScene

Comment: Also I just noticed you are using .ResizeFill in your GameViewController scale mode. You should not do this, your game will look different on each device and it will be a nightmare to manage. You should use the default scaleMode .aspectFill which is usually the best setting.

Comment: and not give the scene the size of the of the bounds (view.bounds.size). You should give it a fixed scene size.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878452/how-to-make-skscene-have-fixed-width/42886511#42886511

Comment: Thx ! I'm actually new to swift thx for the tips anyway. And about the transition actually there no GameOverScene, what I did is basically call the addchild to the HUD where i set my zposition to 50 when the player touches an enemy

Comment: You are welcome about the tips. Could you please update your question again with all the Hud code as well and or any other relevant code. I cannot grasp the full picture yet.

Comment: particularly the showScore and showRestartMenu methods

Comment: actually Im very doubtful about this line of code `interstitialAds.present(fromRootViewController: self)` what does this line of code actually mean, I understand that this line show the ad to the user but does it bring me to the first scene where it shows up when I open the app?

Comment: That line presents the ad from the rootViewController. I think I noticed your mistake. Try moving all the code from ViewWillLayoutSubviews into ViewDidLoad. ViewDidLoad is only called once when the GameViewController loads, whereas ViewWillLayoutSubviews is/can be called multiple times (like when your ad is shown). I updated my answer.

Comment: You are very welcome and thanks for marking. Happy coding.